# Accessing public object variables

Tags: java, oop, singleton, public

I'm writing a Tic-Tac-Toe program and I'm trying to use the method "playOn" from this class in a driver and I'm not sure how I'm suppose to use the public variables (X and O) I've already defined to use that method. It's suppose to be in a "singleton-like" design. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class TTTPlayer {
    public TTTPlayer X = new TTTPlayer('X');
    public TTTPlayer O = new TTTPlayer('O');
    private char symbol;
    private Random gen;
    private boolean playerTurn; // true for 'X', false for 'O'

    private TTTPlayer(char ch) {
        this.symbol = ch;
    }
    public void playOn(TTTBoard board) {
        int row = gen.nextInt(2);
        int col = gen.nextInt(2);
    if (playerTurn) {
        board.place(X, row, col);
        playerTurn = false;
    } else {
        board.place(O, row, col);
        playerTurn = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would assume exactly like you are with `board.place(X, row,col);` and `board.place(O, row, col);`. Why are X and O public exactly?

Comment: Well, in order to insure that no other TTTPlayer instances are created my teacher specified for the constructor to be made private and to create two instances X and O to be made public, and I don't get why because it just makes it harder for me to use its methods. I can't declare a TTTPlayer instance in my driver because it's private, but I can declare it as a variable like this: "TTTPlayer player;" but I can't use any methods with it..

Comment: Well... If they are to be made `public` then I would venture a guess that they will be used **outside** of the class that defines them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you're missing here are static modifiers.

Static members belong to the class, they live a kind of global existence (though they are not necessarily accessible globally). You can access them with a reference to the class, like `out` is a static member of the class `System` so hence `System.out`.

When you create a new object with `new`, it's a unique instance and that holds instance members. `out` is actually an object instance of `PrintStream` so when you say `out.println`, `println` is an instance method.

Some other languages let you declare functions and things in some kind of global namespace but Java doesn't have that, everything has to go in a class. So we have static members.

Here, `X` and `O` are static members like `System.out` but they are also instances of the enclosing class.

```
public class TTTPlayer {
    private char symbol;

    private TTTPlayer(char ch) {
        this.symbol = ch;
    }

    public static TTTPlayer X = new TTTPlayer('X');
    public static TTTPlayer O = new TTTPlayer('O');
    private static Random gen;
    private static boolean playerTurn; // true for 'X', false for 'O'

    public static void playOn(TTTBoard board) {
        int row = gen.nextInt(2);
        int col = gen.nextInt(2);
        if (playerTurn) {
            board.place(X, row, col);
            playerTurn = false;
        } else {
            board.place(O, row, col);
            playerTurn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

To play the turns, you'd call `TTTPlayer.playOn`. Likewise, `X` and `O` are accessed using the name of the class like `TTTPlayer.X` and `TTTPlayer.O`.

If you aren't comfortable with the distinction between instance and static (some people aren't), consider separating these two in to different classes. One that's just for the tokens and another with the static members that makes the moves.

Comment: I agree that `X` and `O` should be `static`. Making `playOn()` static seems questionable.

Comment: @Code-Guru Yes, it could be refactored, I assume you mean so each player makes its own move, but I didn't really want to recommend too much. It's not broken the way it is so it's fine in my book.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I figured it had something to do with the static modifier, but like you said, I'm a little blurry with its distinctions.

Comment: The actual structure of the driver is pretty rigid, so as long as everything else works I'm happy.

Comment: I added a little illustrative example of static/instance to my answer--I hope that helps a little. (My comment just got too long and it's better in the answer anyway.)

Comment: Glad to help. (Time to go to bed.) Also if you think your question's been answered you can [accept one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and it marks the question 'solved'. : )

Comment: Thank you again haha, I would have created an account sooner, but I didn't realize how fast you get responses on here. I'm pleasantly surprised. lol

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with @Radiodef that `X` and `O` should be made `static`. This will solve some of your access issues.

Also, it seems to me that you have two variables that serve the same purpose:

```
private char symbol;
```

This holds an `X` or an `O` to indicate the player.

```
private boolean playerTurn;
```

The comment explicitly states that this also represents either `X` or `O`.

I think the `symbol` variable is more useful because it holds the exact letter to use when taking a turn. If you use this variable, you can simplify the `playOn()` method considerably by keeping in mind that you will have two `TTTPlayer` objects which each store their own `symbol` value.

Finally, you need to also check that a player doesn't try to move in a square that is already taken.

Comment: Yeah.. I do see the redundancy. I tried replacing the boolean with "this.symbol == 'X'" but eclipse says it won't work in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

To have a singleton. You could make the constructor(s) private and use it in a private static field:

```
private static MySingleton = new MySingleton();
```

Then provide an accessor `getMySingleton()`

Also make the players `private` instead of `public` if you can ;)